# maximum likelihood estimation of parameters following polynomial logistic regression

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfiPF.png)

this is the datset, library(frair), data=gammarus

i want to estimate the parameters p0, p1 p2 and p3                 formula is
`*NA/No= exp(P0+   P1*density+   P2*density^2+P3*density^3)/(1+exp(P0+P1*density+ P2*density^2+P3*density^3))*`, where Na is prey eaten and No is prey offered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Setup

```
library(dplyr)
library(frair)

d <- gammarus %>% mutate(y = eaten/(eaten + alive))
```

### Step 1: Regression

You can estimate the coefficients from an equation [image: y = p_0 + p_1 \times x] with the `lm` (linear model) function:

```
lm(y ~ density, data = d)
```

### Step 2: Polynomial regression

To have a polynomial functional form instead, you can use the `poly` function. The first argument is the variable, the second is the degree of the polynomial, and you must then specify whether you want a raw or an orthogonal polynomial. In our case it would be a raw polynomial, check [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258307/raw-or-orthogonal-polynomial-regression) for more detail.

You can estimate the four coefficients from [image: y = p_0 + p_1 x + p_2 x^2 + p_3 x^3] by replacing density with a third degree raw polynomial of density:

```
lm(y ~ poly(density, 3, raw = T), data = d)
```

### Step 3: Logistic regression

The final step is to switch from the linear [image: y = p_0 + p_1 x + p_2 x^2 + p_3 x^3] to the logistic [image: y = \frac{e^{p_0 + p_1 x + p_2 x^2 + p_3 x^3}}{1+e^{p_0 + p_1 x + p_2 x^2 + p_3 x^3}}]. For this you would need the `glm` function (generalized linear model) and you must specify that you want a logit (and not a probit for instance, cf. [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models)) specification with `family = binomial(link = "logit")`.

```
glm(y ~ poly(density, 3, raw = T), data = d, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I am a beginner at R and dont know too much about it, Would you care to explain a few of my questions? 1. does poly function in the code denotes polynomial logistic regression? 2.  what does raw=T stands for and 3. link="logit"

Comment: @mayurwabhitkar I edited my answer to make it clearer. Please consider marking my answer as "accepted" if it did answer your question(s).

Comment: wow sir thanks a lot that was amazing, it took me 15 days to understand it and you sir explained it in minutes 